# Increase performance of trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I'm not a database expert but I am in need of some help making sure a trigger we are using to track an update on a table is the best way to handle our situation and is performing as it should. After loading the trigger we noticed some slow performance on the actual business system (user side).

Background: we are trying to capture the date/time of a transaction that happens so it can be referenced on a customer portal for our website.

The theory: the trigger monitors for a Update to a column to 'PI' and if that happens, it writes data to a table giving some basic information from 2 other tables that are related to to update.

Table 1 columns

```
RH.kbranch, RH.kordnum, RH.kcustnum, RH.custsnum, RH.[program]
```

Table 2 columns

```
RD.kbranch, RD.kordnum, RD.kpart
```

Table 3 columns (where trigger is attached)

```
EQ.kequipnum, EQ.eqpstatus
```

Trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PICKUPTrigger] 
ON [TEST].[dbo].[equip]
FOR UPDATE
AS  
    IF (SELECT eqpstatus FROM inserted) = 'PI'
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        INSERT INTO [Workfiles].[dbo].[PickupAudit] ([HHBranch],[HHOrder],[HHCustomer], [HHShipTo], [EquipID], [EQStatus], [PickupNo], [StatusDate])
            SELECT 
                RH.kbranch, RH.kordnum, RH.kcustnum, RH.custsnum, 
                RD.kpart, EQ.eqpstatus, RH.[program], GETDATE()
            FROM 
                TEST.dbo.renthead RH
            JOIN 
                TEST.dbo.rentdetl RD ON RH.kbranch = RD.kbranch 
                                     AND RH.kordnum = RD.kordnum 
                                     AND RH.program NOT LIKE 'OPSS%'
            JOIN 
                TEST.dbo.equip EQ ON EQ.kequipnum = RD.kpart
            WHERE 
                RD.kpart = (SELECT kequipnum FROM inserted);
END
```

The trigger works, but it appears to be causing problems and slowing down the actual user experience. Any help in tweaking what we have done is appreciated and if you have any questions, feel free to ask.  Thanks.

Comment: The trigger "works" only so far as it's only encountered single row updates thus far. `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Your code only works with 1.

Comment: I would start by looking at the query plan, after fixing the trigger to handle 2+ rows. I suspect you have a lack of indexing if it really is slow when they are just inserting a single row.

Comment: You should use 3 (or 4 part) names ONLY when you need to and you understand the consequences. Generally speaking, you should only use 2 part (schema, object) names. If you (or someone else) ever wants to create another environment (migration, test, development, etc.) then someone must change every 3 part name. It's a little concerning that your "actual business system" uses a database name test - but kudos for using aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You should use explicit `join`s:

```
INSERT INTO [Workfiles].[dbo].[PickupAudit]
([HHBranch],[HHOrder],[HHCustomer],[HHShipTo],[EquipID],[EQStatus],[PickupNo],[StatusDate])    
    SELECT RH.kbranch, RH.kordnum, RH.kcustnum, RH.custsnum, RD.kpart, EQ.eqpstatus, RH.[program], GETDATE()
    FROM TEST.dbo.renthead RH JOIN
         TEST.dbo.rentdetl RD
         ON RH.kbranch = RD.kbranch AND
            RH.kordnum = RD.kordnum AND 
            RH.program NOT LIKE 'OPSS%' JOIN
         TEST.dbo.equip EQ
         ON EQ.kequipnum = RD.kpart JOIN
         inserted i
         ON RD.kpart = i.kequipnum;
```

For performance, you want indexes on the columns used in the `JOIN`s, in this order:

- `TEST.dbo.rentdetl(kpart, kbanch, kordnum)`
- `TEST.dbo.equip(kequipnum)`
- `TEST.dbo.renthead(kbranch, kbanch, program)`

Answer (score 0):

The slow is caused by th join statements, as I think you join heavy tables with data or tables under load sometimes at the trigger operation time

The solution to get better performance is to create "indexed view" not just "view" 
And use it in trigger, and you will see drastically affect